# Загрузка изображений json с помощью ImageLoader

Tags: picasso, json, java, android

Ребят, подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно загрузить изображения с `json` с помощью `ImageLoader`.
Не пойму, как он работает, и не могу внедрить в проект. Т.е. проект уже есть, но я делал изначально с помощью стандартного `DownloadImageTask`. Это не подходит, при загрузке и скролле изображения мелькают и подгружаються постоянно, в общем, бред. Хотел использовать Volly или Picasso, но так и не разобрался с ними. Я новичок в андроиде и со сторонними библиотеками на ВЫ. ImageLoader мне показалось проще, но все равно не разобрался... Кому не сложно, помогите, будет супер, если примером кода.

```
public class ListAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        final PullToRefresh listview = (PullToRefresh) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(index.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Идет загрузка ... Ждемс...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "utf-8");

                    JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(data);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {
                        homelist hmlist = new homelist();
                        JSONObject c = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);

                        hmlist.setTitle(c.getString("title"));

**я так понял, что мне нужно вот сюда его вставить всесто PICTURE** hmlist.setPictures(c.getString("picture"));        
                        hmlist.setHref(c.getString("href"));
                        hmlist.setDate(c.getString("date"));
                        homelist.add(hmlist);

                    }

                    return true;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result == false){

            }else {

                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                adapter = new HListAdapters(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, homelist);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

        }
    }
```

**АДАПТЕР**

```
package avto.avtovesti_end;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class HListAdapters extends ArrayAdapter<homelist> {

    ArrayList<homelist> homelistss;
    int Resource;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater vi;

    public HListAdapters(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<homelist> objects){
        super(context,resource,objects);

        homelistss = objects;
        Resource = resource;
        this.context = context;

        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

          holder.pictures = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
            holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titles);
            holder.date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.href = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.href);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        //holder.pictures.setImageResource();
       new DownloadImageTask(holder.pictures).execute(homelistss.get(position).getPictures());
        holder.title.setText(homelistss.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.date.setText(homelistss.get(position).getDate());
        holder.href.setText(homelistss.get(position).getHref());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        public ImageView pictures;
        public TextView title;
        public TextView href;
        public TextView date;
    }

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage){
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls){
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try{
                InputStream in =new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
            bmImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Покажи свой код, там проще некуда

    ImageLoader.displayImage("url", imageview);

Comment: Выложил...

Comment: Наверное, я ошибаюсь, наверное, не только тут, но еще и в адаптере... сейчас выложу и код адаптера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто.

Подключаешь библиотеку universal image loader.
Далее при запуске приложения конфигурируешь по вкусу:

```
public class App extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
            .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
            .diskCacheSize(5 * 1024 * 1024)
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .build();

    L.writeLogs(true);

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
   }
}
```

В адаптере меняешь строчку

```
new DownloadImageTask(holder.pictures).execute(homelistss.get(position).getPictures());
```

на

```
 ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(homelistss.get(position).getPictures(), holder.pictures);
```

Comment: спасибо,буду пробовать)))

Comment: Спасибо, огромное! )
внедрил и работет отлично)
А случайно не подскажите как в этом приложении мне реализовать LoadMore?